# How to deal with 256 bit numbers in javascript and perfom bitwise operations on them?

Tags: web3js, javascript, bit-manipulation

How to deal with 256 bit numbers in javascript and perform bitwise operations on them?

From here I have read that

> JavaScript stores numbers as 64 bits floating point numbers, but all
> bitwise operations are performed on 32 bits binary numbers.
>
> Before a bitwise operation is performed, JavaScript converts numbers
> to 32 bits signed integers.
>
> After the bitwise operation is performed, the result is converted back
> to 64 bits JavaScript numbers.

I am working with solidity and so it would be great if I could manipulate 256 bit numbers in javascript. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/) library:

```js
const { BigNumber } = require('ethers')
const a = BigNumber.from(1).shl(255) // 1 << 255 = 0x80...00
const b = BigNumber.from(1)          //            0x00...01
const c = a.or(b)                    //            0x80...01
```